# How to fix summernote is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, summernote

I have problem with integrating summernote into my code I keep having this problem. I know there is lot of answer out there but I still can't find solution to mine.

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).summernote is not a function

and When I wrapped it in the `$(document).ready(function() {` I got additional error in my inspect with :

> jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).summernote is not a function TypeError: $(...).summernote is not a function

When I click on the line of error in my inspect it showing me at this line code of mine

`let msg = $("#summernote").summernote("code");`

I have declare the summernote cdn at my header script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#summernote').summernote({
            placeholder: 'description',
            tabsize: 2,
            height:200,
            toolbar:
            [
                ['style', ['style']],
                ['font', ['bold', 'underline', 'clear']],
                ['color', ['color']],
                ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
                ['table', ['table']],
                ['insert', ['link', 'picture', 'video']],
                ['view', ['help']]
            ]
        });    

    });
    

</script>

 <div class="nk-block nk-block-lg">
    <div id="summernote"></div>
 </div>
```

How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my own answer.  I have to declare the script into another file and that is how I solve my own questions.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to solve the error include the summernote js file inside in your click function
Here is the example

```
$.getScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.18/summernote-bs4.min.js', function () 
{
$('.editor').summernote();
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

More than likely the function isn't available while the page is loading (when it hits your script). Try wrapping it in `$(document.ready(function() { /*your code here */ });` to run it after the page finishes loading all its assets (including summernote).

Comment: I have wrapped as you suggested but still no luck, and I got this error when I wrapped it in `document.ready` `jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).summernote is not a function TypeError: $(...).summernote is not a function`

Comment: Here: https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/2087

it looks like versions of summernote must perfectly match jquery. Have you verified this?

Comment: I'm using the` jquery 3.4` and  `summernote 0.8.18`